# Add an arrow with slope and error to a geom_point plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, arrows

I have `xy` data from two groups, where each point also has corresponding `xend` and `yend` coordinates which indicate where an arrow starting at that point ends:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(50,-1,0.5),rnorm(50,1,0.5)),y=c(rnorm(50,-1,0.5),rnorm(50,1,0.5)),group=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)))
df$arrow.x.end <- c(df$x[1:50]+runif(50,0,0.25),df$x[51:100]-runif(50,0,0.25))
df$arrow.y.end <- c(df$y[1:50]+runif(50,0,0.25),df$y[51:100]-runif(50,0,0.25))
```

The arrows of group A generally point towards group B and vice versa:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=group))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y,xend=arrow.x.end,yend=arrow.y.end),arrow=arrow())+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

I'm looking for a way to plot the points with only two arrows, one per each group. 
The arrows will start at centroids of each group, will have a slope which is the median slope of each group. Ideally, the arrows will also have the standard errors of the median slope of each group as polygons.

Here's what I doing so far:

```
library(dplyr)
slope.df <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(slope=(arrow.y.end-y)/abs((arrow.x.end-x)),length=sqrt((arrow.y.end-y)^2+(arrow.x.end-x)^2)) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(slope.median=mean(slope),
                   slope.median.se=1.2533*(sd(slope)/sqrt(n())),
                   median.length=median(length),
                   x.start=median(x),y.start=median(y)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(x.end=x.start+sign(slope.median)*(median.length/sqrt(2))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(y.end=sign(slope.median)*((x.end-x.start)*slope.median))
```

Computing the slope of each arrow and its length. And then per each group the median slope, standard error of the median slope, and the median length. Right now I'm computing `xend` and `yend` of the median arrow as:

```
median.length^2 <- xend^2 + xend^2
```

But I use something else.

So plotting this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=group))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="none")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x.start,y=y.start,xend=x.end,yend=y.end),arrow=arrow(),data=slope.df)
```

Gives:
[image]

Any advice if there's a better way of doing this and also how to add the standard error polygon?

Answer (score 1):

calculate the mean of x and y for each periode

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  select( -c(4,5) ) %>%
  mutate( period = 0 ) %>%
  rbind( data.frame( x = df$arrow.x.end,
                     y = df$arrow.y.end,
                     group = c( rep( "A", 50 ),rep( "B" , 50 ) ),
                     period = 1) 
         ) %>%
  group_by( group, period ) %>%
  summarise_all( mean )

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   group [2]
#   group period      x      y
#   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A          0 -0.950 -1.08 
# 2 A          1 -0.816 -0.942
# 3 B          0  1.06   1.04 
# 4 B          1  0.940  0.905
```

plot, use stat_smooth to draw a line throigh the 'mean' of the clouds

```
ggplot( data = df2, aes( x = x, y = y, colour = group ) ) + 
  stat_smooth(se = TRUE, method = lm, fullrange = TRUE) +
  geom_point( data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group, fill = group ) ) + 
  geom_point( data = df, aes(x = arrow.x.end, y = arrow.y.end, colour = group, fill = group), alpha = 0.5 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel. This is close but won't give an actual standard error polygon.

Comment: @dan That is because you have only got two centers (per cluster)...  so there is no error :)

Comment: I was referring to the error computed by averaging out the arrow slopes per each point :(